Does the photon emitted by a deexciting atom have directionality?
Suppose an atom deexcites and emits a photon. Will the direction in which this photon is emitted (or the direction in which the photon will be measured) be fundamentally random, or is the direction already determined by the properties of the atom? In other words, is it possible to know the direction of emission if you have perfect knowledge about your atom?

In general the EM field is responsible and the EM field behaves somewhat randomly, it is not entirely the atoms properties.  In a laser cavity for example the stimulated emission is in a certain direction.  In a double slit experiment or in an interferometer, path lengths influence where photons will go, the EM field of the apparatus is very important.
If we had perfect knowledge of an atom, yes it would help, we would need perfect knowledge of the surroundings as well .... so its impossible.
Another aspect that is random is the timing of the emission, the excited electron can be excited for a while before causing emission ... all the while during this time the excited electron is influencing or being influenced by the EM field.
